# Automated Form Filling

Tags: javascript, automation

I’m looking for a way to automate a form.  
Here are the details:

1. Extract a certain number (displayed in its html)
2. Do some calculations on the extracted number (percentage of that number)
3. Then automatically fill the remaining input fields with the result instead of typing it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common occurrence in forms. The solution depends on what framework / libraries you're using. Assuming you're using none, here is how you might go about it:

https://jsfiddle.net/f52h1smj/1/

rough HTML:

```
<form>
  <label for="number">Number: </label>
  <input id="number" type="number" />
  <br /> <br />
  <label for="calculatedNumber">Calculated Number (50%): </label>
  <input id="calculatedNumber" type="number" disabled="true" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
(() => {
  //get the form element nodes 
  const $number = document.getElementById("number");
  const $calculatedNumber = document.getElementById("calculatedNumber");

  //add an event listen to the value you're going to use to pre calculate the other fields
  $number.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    //it's value is available like so
    const value = e.target.value;
    //do some validation so that you're calculations don't throw exceptions
    if (Number(value) !== 0 && !Number.isNaN(value)) {
      //set the value of the other inputs to whatever you like by setting the 'value' property of the node. 
      $calculatedNumber.value = value / 2;
    } else {
      $calculatedNumber.value = null;
    }
  });
})();
```

These things become a lot simpler in frameworks like React and Angular.

Comment: Thanks. The actual problem is that, we don't have access to under the Hood.Our strategy was to extract the number from it's html and somehow infuse the the other calculations back into the other input fields based off the calculation gotten off the extracted number

Comment: I’m confused. If you don’t want it to happen when the user types the value, just use $number.value - that gives you the current value of the input.